# Python Playwright pagelocator pass variable

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I made a script that downloads zip-files from a website.  The script needs to locate the correct link and download the file.

I generated the script with codegen and it works, buth the filename is hardcoded.

I would like the script to find the correct link, without the date (filename = "2022-09-26_TEST.zip").  So the script needs to detect the file with TEST and download it.

I can't figure out how to do this.  I already tried passing a variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I pass a variable to the locator and let it search on a piece of the filename (contains)?

```
    with page.expect_download() as download_info:
        page.locator("text=2022-09-26_TEST.zip").click()
        download = download_info.value
        page.wait_for_url("http://192.xx")
        download_filepath = os.path.join(download_path, suggested_filename)
        download.save_as(download_filepath)
        context.close()
        browser.close()



<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>10386</td>
    <td>TEST</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>491</td>
    <td>finished</td>
    <td>
      <a class="text-primary" href="./Exports.php?downloadId=10386">2022-09-26_TEST.zip</a>
    </td>
    <td>2022-09-26 10:17:03</td>
    <td>2022-09-26 10:18:11</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>TEST</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: What does the relevant HTML look like? What's the page? Thanks.

Comment: The link is in a table.  I added the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your question I understand that your problem is not the download itself, your problem is the way of clicking the link that you need.

From that moment, you have to options:

1 - You know the date (exact text):

```
date = "2022-09-26"
with page.expect_download() as download_info:
    page.locator(f"//a[text()='{date}_TEST.zip']").click()
    download = download_info.value
    page.wait_for_url("http://192.xx")
    download_filepath = os.path.join(download_path, suggested_filename)
    download.save_as(download_filepath)
    context.close()
    browser.close()
```

As you can see you can use `f"..{}.."` for your locator string in order to use some vars for the locator, basically a locator is a string.

Of course you should know the date before, in my example is hardcoded.

2 - You don't know the date (Contains text):

```
with page.expect_download() as download_info:
    page.locator(f"//a[contains(text(),'_TEST.zip')]").click()
    download = download_info.value
    page.wait_for_url("http://192.xx")
    download_filepath = os.path.join(download_path, suggested_filename)
    download.save_as(download_filepath)
    context.close()
    browser.close()
```

And being honest, I think the line `page.wait_for_url("http://192.xx")` is not needed. Playwright will wait for your download, actually you don't need to wait for the url, I think.

For my examples I used selector with Xpath.